# Is there any JSP client to access/admin JDBC database?

Tags: java, database, administrator, remote-access

I want a free JSP client to access/administrate my remote database through JDBC interface, 
it should be phpmyadmin-like, and can run within tomcat/resin container, do I have some choices?

Lenik

Comment: I've found a simple jsp named `Zaval Database Front-end':

http://www.zaval.org/products/db-front-end/index.html

It's just a single index.jsp file for doing raw SQL query, I had a try, but it throwed some array index exception and quit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [jspMyAdmin](http://jspmyadmin.sourceforge.net/)?

> jspMyAdmin is a clone of the very popular phpMyAdmin written in JSP.
>
> Support for several database platforms is provided, including MySQL, DBM, and SQLite.

See [features list](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Project%20web#Features) for full details

Comment: Not yet, but is this a MySQL-only client?

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but I've added some more info to my answer. It doesn't seem to support any/all JDBC databases though.